# function that checks if every element of an subarray is the type of string

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to make a battleship like game and i want to make a function that takes an array of objects,then goes throught each specific array in each object and checks if all their elements are "string" type.
Bellow the context, i have an main array  of objects `shipContainer` , then each object has its own array.
`shipContainer = [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ...]`
`obj1.position = [1,2,'hit']`
`obj2.position = [7,'hit','hit','hit']`

now my function looks like this at the moment:

```js
  sunkStatus(shipContainer) {
    const result = shipContainer.every(function (ship) {
      ship.position.every((elem) => typeof elem == "string");
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

problem were i am stuck is that the function returns false no matter if all the objArr's are only string or number and string.

Comment: The `shipContainer.every()` callback doesn't return anything: `return ship.position.every(...)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
const ships = [ {position:[1,2,'hit']}, {position:['hit','hit','hit','hit']}, {position:[3,4,'hit']} ];

function sunkStatus(allShips) {
  return allShips.map(ship=> ship.position.every(el=> typeof el == "string"));
}
// alternatively:
const allSunk = allShips => allShips.every(ship=> ship.position.every(el=> typeof el == "string"));

const status=sunkStatus(ships);
console.log(status, "all ships are sunk: ", status.every(s=>s), allSunk(ships))
```

My `sunkStatus()` function returns an array with information about each ship. In order to chek th overall status you apply `.every()` again.

Or, if you are ony interested in the overall status you can of course also do

```
allShips.every(ship=> ship.position.every(el=> typeof el == "string"));
```

Comment: Why is a missing `return` worth an answer? This should have been a "just a typo" close vote.

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns true when all positions in the array of shipContainers are strings.

```js
    sunkStatus(shipContainer) {
      return shipContainer.reduce((prep, ship) => {
        const isString = ship.position.every((pos) => typeof pos === "string");
        return prep && isString;
      }, true);
    }
```

Find an array other than not String and perform a bit operation with the previous value through &&.